# Getting the languages from Language class

Tags: java, google-translate

I use [this](http://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/downloads/list) Unofficial Java Google Translate API to translate a text from a language to another language.

I have `Language` class that contains the all language names like in the image bellow:
[image]

I want to get an array with the languages names.
How can I do this?

If it would be C# I would do this:

```
PropertyInfo[] languages;
languages = typeof(Language).GetProperties();
```

Comment: I would ask the developer to make this information available as it creates a HashMap with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the fields with

```
Field[] fields = Language.class.getDeclaredFields();

for(Field field: fields) 
   if (field.getType() == String.class)
        System.out.println(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(null));
```

Comment: This is what I am searching. Using `String.valueOf(fields[i])` I can convert it into a string, and then I do what I want with it.

Comment: @John Added an example of what I would do to get name of the Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Language` isn't an `enum` in that library, you'll have to use reflection to find all the members.

Comment: +1 It creates a datastructure with all the names (without using reflection) but this is not available.

Comment: No! This isn't a code writing service! Have a go, learn something new (the reflection API) and come back and ask a (new) specific question if you get stuck. Or hire me. :-)