# Converting from String to field that is a String

Tags: java, google-api, google-translate

I use [this great Java library](http://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/) for converting a text to speech using Google Translate Unofficial API.

Using this code it is able to "read" the text in English (see `Language.ENLGISH`):

```
Audio audio = Audio.getInstance();
InputStream sound  = audio.getAudio("I am a bus", Language.ENGLISH);
audio.play(sound);
```

I have a list (a combobox) with all languages.

How can I convert a string that is `"ENGLISH"` into the field `Language.ENGLISH`?

I don't want to use a lot of `if`s in the code (`if (mySelectedLanguage.equals("ENGLISH") // ...Language.English`).

I already tried with:

- `Language["ENGLISH"]` inspired from Javascript, but it doesn't work
- `Language.class.getField("ENGLISH").toString()` (toString because their types are String: `public static final String ENGLISH`)

Which is the correct way that will really work?

Edit: I already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243203/getting-the-languages-from-language-class) how to get the languages. Maybe it helps us to find the answer.

Comment: Is `Language` enum? If yes then you can use `Language.valueOf("ENGLISH")` to return its `Language.ENGLISH` field.

Comment: No, it doesn't contain `valueOf`. Without languages, it contains only `class`.

Comment: @John So `Language` is not an enum?

Comment: @DuncanJones, No, it isn't.

Comment: Is `ENGLISH` public field? Just asking since `getField` wont return non-public fields.

Comment: @Pshemo, yes, it is: `public static final String ENGLISH`.

Comment: @all, please see this related question about same library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243203/getting-the-languages-from-language-class

Comment: @John Are you sure `Language` is not an `enum`? I searched for it on google and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/api/translate/Language.java?r=54) code.

Comment: @Lonenebula, it's not the same library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get value of public static field

then instead of

```
Language.class.getField("ENGLISH").toString();
```

use

```
(String)Language.class.getField("ENGLISH").get(null);
```

`null` indicates that you don't want to get field from some object, but rather from entire class (which in case of static variable is desired behavior)

---

But if it is possible I would recommend rewriting your Language class to enum and using `Language.valueOf("ENGLISH")`

Comment: If is not a string it throws error: required `String` and found `Object`.

Comment: If you know that field **is** String then you can cast it to it `(String)Language.class.getField("ENGLISH").get(null);`

Comment: Great. I already tried this way, but with `toString()`, and it was throwing an error "It's not convertible..." or something like this. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own enum to store these values. This is good practice regardless of your particular difficulties - by creating a [façade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for this third-party class, you de-couple one part of your code.

If you implement `toString()` as shown below, you can store these enum values directly in your combo box.

```
public enum Languages {

  ENGLISH(Language.ENGLISH, "English"),
  // etc..
  ;

  private final String languageName;
  private final String displayName;

  private Languages(String languageName, String displayName) {
    this.languageName = languageName;
    this.displayName = displayName;
  }

  public String getLanguageString() {
    return languageName;
  }


  public String getDisplayString() {
    return displayName;
  }

  public static Languages fromString(String languageString) {
    for (Language l : values()) {
      if (l.getLanguageString().equals(languageString)) {
        return l;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  // optional
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return displayName;
  }    
}
```

Maybe choose a better name than `Languages` - I'm not feeling very inspired.

Comment: I would use the shortest possible way. Also, I am not a great Java programmer... just playing a little it it.

Comment: @John You asked "*Which is the correct way that will really work?*". I think this answer is the "right" way. The shortest possible way is either your long list of `if` statements, or perhaps just a `Map` mapping Strings to Strings.

Comment: Given that I've written 80% of this class, it may be quite a short route! :-)

Comment: +1, for your answer, but I will not mark it. I already marked another answer. Check it out. It's working!

Comment: @John That's a shame. Not because I care about accepted answers, but because you've resorted to reflection when there are more elegant solutions! Never mind :-)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I said that I prefer the fastest way. It's just a test project about using Google Translate API in this way.